# Robinson Family Crest | English Coat of Arms | "Foi est tout" | is it Latin or French?

Tags: latin

Is the Robinson Family creat motto "Foi Est Tout" written in French or in Latin?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously French: "faith is everything." Modern French requires an article: ***La foi est tout***.

Latin would have been something like ***fides est omnia***.